# Magento Latest Products on home page won't show product category in breadcrumb

Tags: magento, categories, breadcrumbs

On the home page of my Magento site, I used the following code to add a Latest Products block

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="2" template="catalog/product/random.phtml"}}
```

When clicking on one of the products, I am taken to the product page. However, that page does not include the category in the url or the breadcrumb. How can I get the product's category to show up?

Comment: How are your links rendered in `catalog/product/random.phtml`? Show this part of your template.

Comment: @SimonH the link begins like this: <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"